# C# Как добавить form в панель panel

Tags: c#

У меня есть форма.

В неё добавляю панель(может не панель нужна)
И нужно, чтобы вторая форма2 появлялась в рамках рабочего пространства первой формы
ПОдскажите пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это зовется MDI

Comment: Как уже сказали, вам наверняка нужен [MDI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Или смотрите WinAPI-функцию [SetParent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent)

Comment: Только учитывайте, что MDI почему то считают устаревшим интерфейсом. И если Вам переходить в будущем на WPF, там стандартыми средствами не так просто сделать MDI. Как ниже сказали, переходите сразу на tabPage чтобы потом легче было. Если придется связаться с WPF

Answer (score 0):

Тут уже похожий вопрос был, но не про форму, а про табы с формами: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1263202/Дочерняя-форма-при-закрытии-не-закрывается-с-первого-раза/1263235#1263235](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1263202/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0/1263235#1263235)

```
class DaughterForm : Form
{
    public TabPage tabPage; //тот самый TabPage который отвечает за форму
    public DaughterForm()
    {
        this.FormClosed += closed; //дизайнер сам это делает, тут как пример
    }
    void closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabPage?.Parent?.Controls.Remove(tabPage);
    }
}

Form mainform = new Form();
TabControl tc = new TabControl();
tc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
mainform.Controls.Add(tc);
mainform.Show();
mainform.IsMdiContainer = true;

DaughterForm daughterForm = new DaughterForm();
daughterForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
daughterForm.MdiParent = mainform;
daughterForm.Text = "DaughterForm3";
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(daughterForm.Text);
daughterForm.Parent = tabPage;
daughterForm.tabPage = tabPage;
tc.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
daughterForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
daughterForm.Show();
```

Только вместо TabControl используйте Panel и не используйте DockStyle.Fill, функцию closed надо бы переопределить для других полезных целей, например где-нибудь хранить список форм.